# Electron external page errors

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using electron to access external sites and then execute JavaScript in them. The problem is, I run into errors when accessing these sites. On the dev console when I load up paperstorm.it, I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MobileDetect is not defined
>       at paperstorm.it/:57

I have also seen errors when loading up other sites such as
http://www.supremenewyork.com/

> Uncaught TypeError: this.Loader is not a constructor

These errors cause the pages not to work properly, it's an error with how electron loads the page, works fine in other browsers.

I'm loading my page normally:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });
win.loadURL("https://paperstorm.it/")
```

If it's of any help, I'm running electron on arch Linux using electron 1.6.11. and nodejs 8.5.0

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: Oops sorry. I know that lol but somehow the tag slipped in.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to figure out what exactly the issue is. "Some sites don't work" is very vague. For example, maybe you can narrow it down to "secure resources don't load which breaks pages". I'd start with paperstorm. Why is `MobileDetect` undefined on line 57? The script that loads the mobile detect library is right above that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set nodeIntegration to false works.

```
  win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: false,
  }
});
```

For anyone else looking for an answer to this problem. More info on nodeIntegration here: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem where jQuery was not being found in external URLs. Using `'node-integration': false` was not working for me.